# C#: finding nested array in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to find an array nested in a document. The document structure is like this :

```
{
  name:himani;
  user:
  {
    Id: 1,
    Qualification: Programmer,
    PhoneNo: [2524785, 9983410902]
  }
}
```

Now I want to find PhoneNo and add a new number to it. I am using C# driver . Please tell me the way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to add a new PhoneNo 9876543210 to the document with the name hinami:

```
peopleCollection.Update(Query.EQ("name", "himani"), Update.Push("user.PhoneNo", "9876543210"));
```